# sorting tuples in python

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am trying to get the sorted output from following program.

```
"""Count words."""
    # TODO: Count the number of occurences of each word in s

    # TODO: Sort the occurences in descending order (alphabetically in case of ties)

    # TODO: Return the top n words as a list of tuples 


from operator import itemgetter
def count_words(s, n):
    """Return the n most frequently occuring words in s."""

    t1=[]
    t2=[]
    temp={}
    top_n={}

    words=s.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in temp:
            t1.append(word)
            temp[word]=1
        else:
            temp[word]+=1
    top_n=sorted(temp.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0),reverse=True)

    print top_n

    return 


def test_run():
    """Test count_words() with some inputs."""
    count_words("cat bat mat cat bat cat", 3)
    count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

This program output is like:

```
[('cat', 3), ('bat', 2), ('mat', 1)]

[('butter', 2), ('was', 1), ('the', 1), ('of', 1), ('but', 1), ('bought', 1), ('bitter', 1), ('bit', 1), ('betty', 1), ('a', 1)]
```

but I need in the form like:

```
[('cat', 3), ('bat', 2), ('mat', 1)]

[('butter', 2), ('a', 1),('betty', 1),('bit', 1),('bitter', 1) ... rest of them here]
```

COuld you please let me know the best possible way?

Comment: They are immutable, but sort-able. And dict wouldn't fit here, unless you only use the array part of dictionary. Or if you change the question altogether. Lists would be an option, though.

Comment: can u guys suggest any modification in the above code only so that it gives the desired output

Comment: What is `(<word>, <count>)`

Comment: typo mistake in my local editor.. removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `key` function you're giving to `sorted`, since the items in your desired output need to be sorted in descending order by count but ascending order alphabetically. I'd use a `lambda` function:

```
top_n = sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))
```

By negating the count, an ascending sort gets you the desired order.

Comment: can we limit the number of items to be return by sorted by passing any argument ?

Comment: No, `sorted` always sorts the whole list. To get just the first `n` values, use a slice: `top_n = top_n[:n]`

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
top_n=sorted(temp.items(), key=itemgetter(1,0),reverse=True)
```

To:

```
temp2=sorted(temp.items(), key=itemgetter(0),reverse=False)
top_n=sorted(temp2.items(), key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
```

and thanks to the [Sort Stability](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts) you will be good

Comment: how temp2 shud be defined here?  like this temp2={} ??

Comment: @ManishKumar the first line define temp2, and the seconed use it. you don't need to initialize it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `itemgetter`, use `lambda t:(-t[1],t[0])` and drop the `reverse=True`:

```
top_n=sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda t:(-t[1],t[0]))
```

This returns the same thing as `itemgetter(1,0)` only with the first value inverted so that higher numbers will be sorted before lower numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
def count_words(s, n):
"""Return the n most frequently occuring words in s."""

    t1=[]
    t2=[]
    temp={}
    top_n={}

    words=s.split()
    for word in words:
        if word not in temp:
            t1.append(word)
            temp[word]=1
        else:
            temp[word]+=1
    top_n=sorted(temp.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1], t[0]),reverse=True)

    print top_n

    return 


def test_run():
"""Test count_words() with some inputs."""
    count_words("cat bat mat cat bat cat", 3)
    count_words("betty bought a bit of butter but the butter was bitter", 3)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_run()
```

I used `lambda` instead of itemgetter and in other apps I've written, lambda seems to work.